# Search a string in the table populated in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

My HTML page looks like this.

[image: search window]

I have an `array` doing `ng-repeat` I print the data in the tabular format on my `html` page. In the search box if I enter 'User3' that specific row only has to be shown on my `html` page or all the rows that match the search string need to be shown. Can that be done using only angular or call to the DB has to be done to achieve this?

Since I have the complete data in the `array` is it necessary to query the DB again?

Comment: it can be done in angular.... read about filters... but then if you have too much data, better to do it on server

Comment: You can use a module such as [smart-table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/)

Comment: **smart-table** is what I am exactly looking for. @MoshFeu can this be used for large data as well?

Comment: @entre data can vary. I am trying to avoid calls to DB as much as possible.

Comment: @Jil `large data` is vague definition. Keep it in your mind that in all page move (I mean pagination) all the rows renders again. So if you will use many directives with DOM manipulation (like custom select boxes etc.) you will see a short delay until the final view. In other words, this module is not just show/hide rows but do manipulations in the DOM for each action (like search or paging). I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @MoshFeu Thank you. I get that :)

Comment: My pleasure :) You know what? If it's OK with you, I will post a demo in an answer then please accept it so it will help to other people. What do you think?

Comment: [ng-table](http://ng-table.com/#/) I found this during my search. That put me to a thought on what is the difference between `ng-table` and `smart-table` @MoshFeu

Comment: i think, if you have used ng-repeat for showing each row, then you can use filter only. no need to use one more extra lib

Comment: @nitz Thank you :)